# Post with zeroes in all windows.

Tags: support

Hi: Would you mind looking at this post:
[Let $N$ be an abelian minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Then $N$ has a complement in $G$ iff $N\not\leq \Phi(G)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788953/let-n-be-an-abelian-minimal-normal-subgroup-of-g-then-n-has-a-complement)
In it not only the question but all three answers have zeroes on the left side. I find this weird. Any particular reason for it to have zeroes in all the windows?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of what you are seeing?  I see nothing wrong with that question.  Are the zeros, perhaps, the vote totals?

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason that you posted two answers, rather than editing the older answer?

Comment: Yes, the theorem was in the form of a logical equivalence. In the first answer I posted one of the implications. And in the other the other implication that was missing in the first answer. I had certain experience with this thing of "do I comment or answer?" Not long ago in a thread opened by me, I commented: "I edited the question adding more information". There I showed some of my progress in the solution to the problem. From that moment on, the thread was dead. Nobody cared to post in the thread.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing weird.

One person bothered to upvote the question, and one person bothered to downvote the question. These cancelled out to 0. Nobody bothered to vote any of the answers, so they are all scored 0 as well.

These things happen. If you want to do something about it, vote the competing answers (if they are helpful) or the question, if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: The question and 2/3 answers are by the OP only, so their only choice is to vote on the other answer.

Comment: Right. I did not notice all of that. But the point remains.

Comment: Oh yes, certainly.

Comment: Well, up to now, and I have already posted some hundred questions, I always had at least a one on the left of the question. This thing alone is weird (for me). Maybe the fact that the question contains an enmbeded image made some users to despise it?